# Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be IID with mean $\mu$. (a) Show that E($X_1$| $X_1+X_2$) =$\dfrac {(X_1 +X_2)}{2}$.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be IID with mean $\mu$.

(a) Show that E($X_1$| $X_1+X_2$) =$\dfrac {(X_1 +X_2)}{2}$.

(b) Show that in general E($X_1$| $X_1X_2$)$\neq$ $\sqrt {X_1X_2}$

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 2):

(a) By symmetry $$\alpha = E(X_1|X_1+X_2)=E(X_2|X_1+X_2).$$

$$2\alpha = E(X_1|X_1+X_2)+ E(X_2|X_1+X_2) = E(X_1+X_2|X_1+X_2) = X_1+X_2,$$

$$\alpha = \frac{1}{2} (X_1+X_2).$$

(b) Again, invoking symmetry, we want to show that

$$E(X_1|X_1X_2) E(X_2|X_1X_2) \ne E(X_1X_2|X_1 X_2)=X_1X_2.$$

Well, since we are showing an inequality, a counterexample should be sufficient.

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent standard normal random variables (mean $\mu=0$, variance $\sigma^2 =1$).  If the product $X_1X_2$ is positive, are we expecting $X_1$ and $X_2$ to both be positive.  Or are they both negative?  The conditional distribution of $X_1$ may no longer be gaussian, but it will be symmetric, and thus $E(X_1|X_1X_2) = 0 \ne X_1X_2$ (unless $X_1X_2=0$).